# Cannot get into BIOS or boot from disk on Samsung NP300 laptop

Tags: boot, partitioning, 16.04, windows, uefi

I have problem with my laptop Samsung NP300-E5C-A02PL. I had Ubuntu 16.04, but I decided to change my operating system to Windows 10 (It was working before, let's say 1 year ago).

At boot time I only can see a black screen or a screen like this.

[image]

I'm not able to boot from disk or even get into BIOS.

I read lots of posts about similar issue, but nothing helped, so I decided to ask you about it. I've already tried:

- using other keys on boot (F3 works for booting from CD, F8 or F9 from USB)
- using external keyboard on USB and pushing F2 and other keys
- take off BIOS battery for 30 sec
- connect together pins RESET on the motherboard for 30 sec
- install Windows 10 using MBR (diskpart -> convert mbr)
- install Windows 10 using GPT (diskpart -> convert gpt)
- install Ubuntu (old - 9.04) on other partition

Comment: That is a really bad problem. I had the same laptop and the same problem. Never try to boot it in UEFI mode. The solution is to boot from Windows Live CD. Only CD works, not USB. Then find firmware in the net for this laptop and the utility to flash, that can install it from a file. This is not easy to find. I have that at home. Then run this utility with a parameter to clear UEFI variables. After that you will be able to get into bios and switch off UEFI boot for ever. The issue is not related to Ubuntu at all. This is a Samsung UEFI bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash BIOS was a sole option to solve this problem. It wasn't so simple so I want to share it with others who have similar problem.

Firstly, I was need to download Windows PE and burn it on DVD. For me the best was Gandalf's Windows7 PE. I could run it using F3 on startup. Then I was need to install drivers to my network card (from USB stick).

It is probably not possible to find proper file of BIOS in Internet (PO5RAJ in my case). Even Samsung support couldn't help me with that. However, here is a good solution how to extract ROM file from Samsung utility for Bios Update: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/samsung-laptops-roll-back-bios-updates.696197/
You can use WinFlash which also is in Temp directory, but be shure to check option "Remove variables", beause without it you'll see no changes with your BIOS.